# Fazer com que o Python remova um termo específico de uma str que será adicionada a um arquivo .txt

Tags: python, lista, arquivo, txt, python-requests

**A proposta desse código é adicionar termos em uma mesma linha de um arquivo plain text, sem repetir termos.**

Consegui chegar até o seguinte código sozinho:

```
lista = []

x = int(input('Digite 1 para começar o programa e 0 para pará-lo: '))

if x == 1:

    while x == 1:
        y = input('Digite o nome que você gostaria de adicionar e 0 quando quiser parar: ')
        if y == '0':
            break
        lista.append(y)

        for z in range(len(lista)):
            if lista[z] == '':
                del(lista[z])

    listaOrdem = sorted(lista)

    with open('arquivolista.txt', 'a') as arquivo:
        arquivo.write(str(listaOrdem))
    with open('arquivolista.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
        print(arquivo.read())

else:
    print('O programa foi encerrado.')
```

- Agora, preciso de uma forma para fazer com que o Python identifique quais termos já estão presentes no arquivo e não os adicione novamente. Também preciso que o output saia organizado, sendo assim, preciso que os colchetes extras sejam apagados.

**Exemplo:**

- Quando rodo o programa pela primeira vez e adiciono os termos:

> "Gorila", "Cachorro" e "Girafa"

- O arquivo plain text fica:

> ['Cachorro', 'Girafa', 'Gorila']

- Quando rodo pela segunda vez e adiciono os termos:

> "Leão", "Girafa", "Pantera" e "Baleia"

- O arquivo plain text fica:

> ['Cachorro', 'Girafa', 'Gorila']['Baleia', 'Girafa', 'Leão', 'Pantera']

- Preciso fazer com que o termo 'Girafa' não se repita e que os colchetes extras sejam apagados, para que o output final seja:

> ['Baleia', 'Cachorro', 'Girafa', 'Gorila', 'Leão', 'Pantera']

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Aproveite e faça o nosso [tour]

Comment: Não falo pelos outros usuários, mas em minha opinião essa não é melhor maneira de fazer o que pretende. Aparentemente você codifica bem, porém o uso dum arquivo de texto plano não é a ferramenta indicada para persistir estruturas de dados em Python, isso porque para salvar estruturas de dados em texto plano, sem recorrer a gambiarras e tosquices, é preciso definir uma gramatica de serialização de objetos e para recuperar estruturas de dados em texto plano é preciso criar um analisador dessa gramatica para deserialização dos objetos. Demanda um considerável esforço para um problema simples.

Comment: A linguagem Python oferece nativamente [suporte a persistência de dados](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/persistence.html) assim como suporte nativo ao formato [JSON](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/json.html). Pessoalmente faço uso considerável do formato JSON pela facilidade de intercambio com outras linguagens e tecnologias, talvez seja o mais adequado ao seu caso. Mas volto a frisar é somente minha opinião.

Answer (score -1):

Bem cara, existem algumas formas legais de se fazer isso e eu procurei fazer da forma que abordasse mais assuntos para ajudar você a estudar mais coisas.

```
lista = []

x = int(input('Digite 1 para começar o programa e 0 para pará-lo: '))

if x == 1:

    while x == 1:
        y = input(
            'Digite o nome que você gostaria de adicionar e 0 quando quiser parar: ')
        if y == '0':
            break
        lista.append(y)

        for z in range(len(lista)):
            if lista[z] == '':
                del(lista[z])

    with open('arquivolista.txt', 'a+') as arquivo:
        # Primeiro vamos ler o que já temos
        dados = arquivo.read()
        # Apos isso vamos retirar os [] e '
        dados = dados.replace('[', '').replace(']', '')
        dados = dados.replace("'", "").replace('"', '')
        # Agora vamos separar os termos em uma list
        if dados == '':
            dados = []
        else:
            dados = dados.split(', ')
        # o extends add os termos de uma lista em uma já existente
        dados.extend(lista)
        # Agora vem a parte legal, vamos usar um set que nada mais é que um conjunto
        # e assim como na matemática conjutos não contém repetições
        dados = set(dados)
        # Agora é só salvar! E re-transformar em uma lista
        listaOrdem = sorted(list(dados))
    # Abrindo ele no modo W ele apaga tudo que existe
    with open('arquivolista.txt', 'w') as arquivo:
        arquivo.write(str(listaOrdem))

    with open('arquivolista.txt', 'r') as arquivo:
        print(arquivo.read())

else:
    print('O programa foi encerrado.')
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).